# Jsoup: Safe Elements.get(0)

Tags: html, html-parsing, jsoup

The following snippet of code extracts one and only one element, specifically the *first* element:

```
  String linkHref = "";
  String linkText = "";
  Elements links = div.getElementsByTag("a");
  for (Element link : links) {
    linkHref = link.attr("href");
    linkText += link.text();              
    break;
  }
```

This is really cumbersome code compared to the concise `links.get(0)` but it has one important feature: It will **not** throw an `IndexOutOfBoundException` if Elements is empty. Instead, it will simply leave the strings empty.

I can encapsulate this into my own function but it's hard for me to believe that Jsoup doesn't have such function already (I prefer using library function over "re-inventing the wheel" as much as possible). I searched the documentation but couldn't find any.

Do you know whether such "safe `Elements.get(0)`" exists in Jsoup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[elements.first()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#first%28%29) returns the first element from elements, or null if empty.

Also you can use [elements.isEmpty()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#isEmpty%28%29) to check if anything matches your selector.

E.g., depending on what you are trying to do:

```
Element link = div.select("a").first();
if (link != null) {
  String href = link.attr("href");
  String text = link.text();
}
```

Comment: Wow! I was about to answer myself with `elements.isEmpty() ? null : elements.get(0);` but yours is so much better. +1 :)

Comment: More authorative you can't get the answer ;) (Jonathan is the author of Jsoup)